# What kind of companies sponsor pro teams? What makes a team pro?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do professional teams invite new players onto their teams?

How does a team become professionally recognised?

Do you need to have a sponsor, and if so, how would you get one?

What kind of companies sponsor gaming teams?

Comment: While I believe the base questions (How do you get onto a team and what make a team pro) are not a good fit for the site, some of the questions in your posted could benefit from being posted in their own question. Remember that you should only ask one question per post, we don't care if you have to do 5 posts at the same time to do it, it is much easier to answer them correctly if they are separated.

Comment: is there a way you could tell me what questions I should separate?

Comment: Conjim, helpful hint! if you want to make sure someone sees your response, address them with `@<username>` - @Jupotter in this instance. ♪

Comment: @Raven Dreamer thank you for your hint I tried to revise the question I dont know if I did it right though and now I see some one has revised it since I re-wrote it.

Comment: @conjim I think I answered your question pretty convincingly, if there's anything else you're curious on feel free to reply to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do pro teams invite new players onto their teams?

Rarely, usually only to fill an open slot when a player retires or leaves the team. Typically teams are recruited as a group of 5 or 6 and stay together, often even across multiple sponsors.

> How does a team become pro?

If your team records successful results in open tournaments, this results in invitations to more prestigious tournaments. If you consistently do well in these kinds of tournaments, your team can attract a legitimate sponsor or gaming organization that you can represent.

> Do you have to have a sponsor, and if so, how would you get one?

You don't have to, but typically sponsors pay for players to travel to and from events, for their hotels there, and in some cases also salaries or housing. Without a sponsor, it's hard to be a full time gamer.

> What kind of companies sponsor gaming teams?

In the past, sponsors for gaming teams have been largely gaming/computer related. As the community surrounding competitive gaming grows larger, sponsors related to the demographic are becoming more and more interested. Frequent sponsors are AMD/Intel/MSI/Kingston who produce computer parts, Steelseries/Razer/Kingston who produce accessories like headsets, keyboards, mice, etc., and some age-related companies like Monster, Dr Pepper, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Wow quite a few questions for 1 link.  There are only a handful of pro-players and only a handful of pro-teams.

To answer your questions, normally there are a few players who play together quite frequently.  They add them to the friends list and get a player for each role, Ability power, Jungle, Ranged AD, Tank, and Support.  It is best that you have multiple roles/champs that you can play that way if someone cannot or does not want to play a certain role you can.

Pro-teams are normally by tryout.  They play quite a few private games daily and play against players who are in the same ELO as they are.  As for communications quite a few teams use IRC to setup times, Teamspeak, Mumble, or if someone has enough bandwidth maybe even skype.

In order to be sponsored it helps to have a recognizable face of the team, Dyrus or Ocelete are two of the most recognizable due to their connections on Twitter.  Hopefully this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the ESL (http://www.nationalesl.com/us/). You can sign up for an account there and a lot of times teams will be looking for new members there. If you're good enough you can get on a team. The teams you're likely to get on are amateur teams that mainly compete in the Go4LoL cups and the ESL's Open League that's starting really soon. It's highly unlikely that you'll be able to get onto a pro team, but if you're good, maybe you could take an amateur team to the top levels of play ;-).